# Oracle - Utf_file.get_line not reading utf8 csv lines properly

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I have an utf8 csv file from which I want to read from.
It contains characters like ç, á, à ã...

This is what I'm doing:

```
CSVFile := utl_file.fopen (UPPER('dummyDIR'), CSV_name, 'r', 32767);
utl_file.get_line(CSVFile,CSVLine);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('line obtained with get_line: '||CSVLine);
```

And all the special characters get weird...
Any idea how I can get the correct charset read?

This is what I get in Linux to check the charset:

```
echo $NLS_LANG
PORTUGUESE_PORTUGAL.UTF8
```

Comment: What is the database character set, which client are you using, and what is your OS (and/or terminal emulator) character set? How is CSVLine declared?

Comment: Your question gave me an idea that worked out: select * from nls_database_parameters; gave me the db charset. then just needed to CONVERT(CSVLine,'dbCHARSETFORMAT','UTF8');

Comment: [Oracle discourages use of `convert()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONVERT.html). If your DB charset doesn't support those characters then it *might* be more appropriate to use the national character set, via `nvarchar2` variables and [`utl_file.get_line_nchar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-34D23D36-3D81-4EFB-8F59-9D5C7BA0E4E7). Or that might give you other problems, it depends *8-)